# read cdata in xml from javascript

Tags: xml, cdata

```xml
<data>
  <![CDATA[test]]>
</data>
```

I am getting blanks.

```js
var dataNode=Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('data',xml);
console.log(dataNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
console.log(dataNode.nodeValue);
```

Comment: Can we see the XML in question?

Comment: There's no question, no context, no nothing.

Comment: The XML was hidden in the original question, thus all the comments about missing XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst we can't say for sure without the XML that's being parsed, the usual reason for ‘getting blanks’ from `childNodes[0]` (`firstChild`) is that there is a whitespace Text node between the parent's start-tag and the node you are looking for:

```
<data>
    <![CDATA[ foo ]]>
</data>
```

On an XML parser that retains CDATA sections, that'll give the `data` element three children: a Text node containing a newline and some spaces; the CDATASection node; and another Text node with a newline.

So you *could* take `childNodes[1]`, but it's a bit fragile... in particular it would break for an XML parser that turns CDATA sections into text, where you'd get a single Text child containing `foo` and all the whitespace. Probably better to take the `textContent` of the `<data>` element (except of course with fallback to `innerText` for IE).

Comment: FYI, as this post is 12 years old (as of this comment), the information about IE is out of date. `textContent` has [been supported since IE9](https://caniuse.com/textcontent).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xml = parser.parseFromString('XML_GOES_HERE', 'text/xml').documentElement;

const someElement = xml.getElementsByTagName('MY_TAG');

// using `wholeText` will allow us to read CDATA when it's located in a new line
const cdataValue = someElement?.firstChild?.wholeText?.trim();
```

Comment: This worked for parsing XML RSS traffic reports in 2022

Comment: Alex, can you please explain what the "googleable" term is for all those question marks? This looks like a cousin of a ternary conditional, but I've never run across it until now and I'd like to learn more. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I found it! This is called the `optional chaining operator` and replaces ternaries or statements with `&&` (source: https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-variable-question-mark/). The optional chaining operator prevents throwing a JS exception and instead returns undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Try .contents() to return the whole thing (including CDATA) - http://api.jquery.com/contents/