# JS innerHTML changes content, how to parse this?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html:

```
<string name="finish_registration_title">
    <![CDATA[
    Hello <b>%1$s</b> …
    ]]>
</string>
```

I need to extract its content, but `innerHTML` changes the content to:

```
<!--[CDATA[
    Hello <b-->%1$s …
]]&gt;
```

It creates a comment.

According to the [docs of innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) I should use `textContent`, but it gives me:

```
%1$s …
]]>
```

I have not found an other solution yet. I just need the inner content of the `string` tag as it is in the `string` tag.

Comment: Could it have something to do with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736122/read-cdata-in-xml-from-javascript

Comment: How exactly do you “have this HTML”? You can not get stuff with JavaScript _after_ parsing, that the browser has already discarded or error-corrected into something else _during_ parsing.

Comment: I copy paste it from an XML file into my tool, which then parses the file by key values, so other people can create translations.

Comment: It's XML, not HTML. You need to use either XML or XHTML to parse it.